# Quartz sheduler throws out of memory

Tags: quartz-scheduler, out-of-memory

My quartz job throws an error below.
Does anyone know how to fix out of memory problem?

```
Exception in thread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:197)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.resolve(Win32FileSystem.java:259)
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:341)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1449)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0):

The out of memory exception in your quartz job is likely to be a symptom and not the cause of your problem. Your application is likely to be close to exhausting the available heap when your job runs.

You may have a memory leak (eg an ever expanding collection) elsewhere. You will need to use a profiler to find this problem.

Or it may be the case that you need to allocate more heap space for your application. In this case you could set the -Xmx argument in your catalina script used to start Tomcat.

Comment: I've tried -Xmx as you suggested. It works better but it still requires too much memory.

Comment: What is profiler?
Can you guide me since I've never used it before?

Comment: A profiler is a tool that enables you analyse the performance of your application. For memory profiling I have successfully used the Eclipse Memory Analyser in the past, http://www.eclipse.org/mat/  You can run it standalone if Eclipse is not your preferred IDE.